# Legend overlapping my graph in JS

Tags: javascript, css, margin

I tried resolving the problem by using marginBottom with % values. My graph container size is also written in terms of %.

It didn't work and my page isn't responding. Help me out with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give more details in your question. Post some of the code involved and people might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make sure your graph container is within a parent container with an explicitly defined height value. Otherwise, your responsive design using % values will not work.